# Capacity of Bolt in Apache Storm is over 1

Tags: apache-storm

As per the given link the capacity of a bolt is the percentage of time spent in executing. Therefore this value should always be smaller than 1. But in my topology I have observed that it is coming over 1 in some cases. How is it possible and what does it mean ?[image: Storm UI snap]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwuRP.png

Answer (score 3):

It means that your bolt is running over capacity and your topology will fall behind in processing if the bolt is unable to catch up.

When you see a bolt that is running over (or close to over) capacity, that is your clue that you need to start tuning performance and tweaking parallelism.

Some things you can do:

1. Increase the parallelism of the bolt by increasing the number of executors & tasks.
2. Do some simple profiling within your slow bolts to see if you have a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more detail about what's happens in your bolts using Storm Metrics

https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Metrics.html